# Using OnPost Page Handlers for AJAX Requests in Razor Pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I have a JavaScript/jQuery function used to execute AJAX requests as part of a ASP.NET Core Razor Pages (Visual C#) project. The AJAX request calls an "OnGet" handler method in the PageModel (.cshtml.cs) of whichever page it gets called on.
AJAX request JS/jQuery:

```
function conditionalDropDown(parameters) {

//code to get handler method inputs in correct format

var pathname = window.location.pathname;
var handler = "?handler=ConditionalDropDown";
var actionpath = pathname + handler;

$.ajax({
    dataType: 'json',
    url: actionpath,
    type: 'GET',
    data: {
        parameterName: parameterValue
    },
    beforeSend: function (xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader("XSRF-TOKEN",
            $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val());
    },
    success: function (data) {
        //dealing with the data returned by the request
    },
    error: function () {
        alert("AJAX Request Failed, Contact Support");
    }
});
}
```

Handler Method in PageModel:

```
public JsonResult OnGetConditionalDropDown(parameters)
    {
        //call a function to get the return string

        return new JsonResult(dropdownHTML);
    }
```

I want to change my AJAX request such that it uses an "OnPost" handler method instead. I have tried changing `type: 'GET'` to `type: 'POST'` in the AJAX request function, and the name of the handler method from `OnGetConditionalDropDown` to `OnPostConditionalDropDown` but the request always fails.

I have `@Html.AntiForgeryToken()` added to the page (.cshtml) from which the AJAX request is sent, but I'm not sure it's in the right place. Currently, I have it inside the `<form>` tags of the form from which the AJAX requests are called.

I think I'm missing something in the way the request is set up, but I have no idea what it is. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answering my own question...

1. AJAX Request - removed `beforeSend` function in request, replaced with: `headers: { "RequestVerificationToken": $('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val() },` in request initialisation.
2. AJAX Request - changed `type: 'GET'` to `type: 'POST'`
3. Handler Method - `OnGet` --> `OnPost`
4. Page .cshtml - removed `@Html.AntiForgeryToken()`, added `method="post"` to form from which AJAX request is made

Works perfectly now!